# Keyword Search from separate dataframe

Tags: r, tokenize

I have some R code below with examples of the 2 dataframes that I'm working with. The "keywords" df is periodically changing, so I need to create some code that will FLAG the rows within "mydata" where the Segment matches and the mydata$Acct_Name only needs to contain the word from keywords$KEYWORD somewhere within the cell.

I started doing a FOR loop, but things get tricky quickly when you're dealing with grepl and multiple dataframes. My next thought was to parse mydata$Acct_Name to then attempt a merge between the 2 dfs.

Any help is much appreciated!

## dummy data

```
Acct_Name <- c('joes ski shop'
               ,'joes alarm shop'
               ,'joes alarm spot'
               ,'joes bakery'
               ,'joes albergue shop'
               ,'jims Brewery'
               ,'jims albergue place'
               )
Segment <- c('All_Other'
             ,'All_Other'
             ,'All_Other'
             ,'All_Other'
             ,'Apartments'
             ,'Apartments'
             ,'Apartments'
             )

mydata <- data.frame(Acct_Name, Segment)

mydata$Acct_Name <- as.character(mydata$Acct_Name)
mydata$Segment <- as.character(mydata$Segment)


Segment <- c('All_Other'
             ,'All_Other'
             ,'All_Other'
             ,'Apartments'
             ,'Apartments'
             ,'Apartments'
             ,'Apartments'
)
KEYWORD <- c('aislamiento'
             ,'alarm'
             ,'alarma'
             ,'albergue'
             ,'alcantarilla cloaca'
             ,'alcohol'
             ,'almacenamiento'
)

keywords <- data.frame(Segment,KEYWORD)
keywords$FLAG <- 1
keywords$Segment <- as.character(keywords$Segment)
keywords$KEYWORD <- as.character(keywords$KEYWORD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find any of the keywords for the group within the entries in `mydata` for that group. We can basically just collapse each group to one `or` condition, using `paste`, with the `collapse = "|"` specified. Then do a merge and make a new column of results using `grepl`. Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
# make the conditions, collapsing by group
kwords <- as.data.table(keywords)[, KWORD := paste(KEYWORD, collapse = "|"), by = Segment
  ][, .SD[1], by = Segment, .SDcols = c("KWORD")]

# make a column based on the grepl with condition
mydata <- as.data.table(mydata)
kwords[mydata, on = "Segment"][, flag := grepl(KWORD, Acct_Name), by = Acct_Name][]

# output:
# Segment                                               KWORD           Acct_Name  flag
# 1:  All_Other                            aislamiento|alarm|alarma       joes ski shop FALSE
# 2:  All_Other                            aislamiento|alarm|alarma     joes alarm shop  TRUE
# 3:  All_Other                            aislamiento|alarm|alarma     joes alarm spot  TRUE
# 4:  All_Other                            aislamiento|alarm|alarma         joes bakery FALSE
# 5: Apartments albergue|alcantarilla cloaca|alcohol|almacenamiento  joes albergue shop  TRUE
# 6: Apartments albergue|alcantarilla cloaca|alcohol|almacenamiento        jims Brewery FALSE
# 7: Apartments albergue|alcantarilla cloaca|alcohol|almacenamiento jims albergue place  TRUE
```

EDIT:
Another option, that might work when there are many keywords per group, is to use `stringr::str_detect`, which is vectorized over pattern. Like so:

```
as.data.table(mydata)[, flag := any(
  stringr::str_detect(Acct_Name, 
                      keywords[keywords$Segment == Segment,"KEYWORD"])), 
  by = Acct_Name][]

# Acct_Name    Segment  flag
# 1:       joes ski shop  All_Other FALSE
# 2:     joes alarm shop  All_Other  TRUE
# 3:     joes alarm spot  All_Other  TRUE
# 4:         joes bakery  All_Other FALSE
# 5:  joes albergue shop Apartments  TRUE
# 6:        jims Brewery Apartments FALSE
# 7: jims albergue place Apartments  TRUE
```

We want to see if, for the subset of `keywords` such that `keywords$Segment == mydata$Segment`, `any` of the patterns from `keywords$KEYWORD` can be found with `str_detect` in `mydata$Acct_Name`. This solution seems a little funky to me, because it mixes a few different methods of referencing columns and mixes data.frame and data.table, but it seems to work. Perhaps this will work with the size of your original data.

Or, instead of having to repeatedly subset, make a list beforehand and use that (using `split` to split the data.frame, the equivalent of subsetting here, and `lapply` to get only the `KEYWORD` column):

```
keywords.list <- lapply(split(keywords, keywords$Segment), function(x) x$KEYWORD)
```

Then refer to each conveniently named list item by the value of `Segment` in mydata:

```
as.data.table(mydata)[, flag := any(
  stringr::str_detect(
    Acct_Name, 
    keywords.list[[Segment]])), by = Acct_Name][]

# Acct_Name    Segment  flag
# 1:       joes ski shop  All_Other FALSE
# 2:     joes alarm shop  All_Other  TRUE
# 3:     joes alarm spot  All_Other  TRUE
# 4:         joes bakery  All_Other FALSE
# 5:  joes albergue shop Apartments  TRUE
# 6:        jims Brewery Apartments FALSE
# 7: jims albergue place Apartments  TRUE
```

Comment: Tom - this is great, but unfortunately, in my actual "keywords" df I have over 500k rows, so I don't see this method working since the KWORD column wouldn't be able to handle that size. Let me know if you happen to have any other ideas! Thanks!

Comment: @AHud How many rows per `Segment` in keywords? A problem could arise if there are too many keywords within each `Segment` because, I think, `grepl` can handle only a "small" regex.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, however, I'm getting this error when I run:  Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

Comment: Based on a quick search, it appears that I need to escape the parentheses? "\\("   not sure where to insert this?

Comment: Make a new column in keywords, using either `base::gsub` or `stringr::str_replace_all`, and then use that column instead of KEYWORD. Also, you will probably need to escape them like "\\(" using two backslashes. If the answer is satisfactory for your original question, you should accept it :)

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. I will clean up the KEYWORD column.

Comment: Works great and relatively quick!  Thanks again for all your help!